# Change WIndows File Permission With Total Size Around 1 TB

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, file-permissions, file-sharing

Now I am working in company that had file server. When I see the permission of file sharing I almost got hearth attack because in root directory "Everyone" had full permission and will inherited by sub folder and files.

The total size almost 1 TB, I plan to change the permission especially remove "Everyone" using icacls but I am afraid such size will make issue in process and could make the folders and files not consistent.

We had the backup but 1 TB I think will take quite time to recover and I am afraid it will disturb the users.

Anyone here had been change permission for file server/sharing with close to that size, I need your opinion and advice.

Comment: Before you do anything, make sure that management understands the problem and agrees with the solution.

Comment: I am single IT here and already tell them the danger of such things. Due to no sure knowledge of IT security they just ignored it like it was nothing.

Comment: I also already tell the our HQ IT team that had higher privileged than me for managing the server but due to they basic was programming they not really care at all such issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the management does not fully understand the problem, maybe you should not risk to change the ACLs: after all, if some problem arise, in their eyes **you** caused an issue to correct an already "working" solution.

Moreover, you are correct in thinking that changing the ACLs on such an amount of files is a challenging operation, both from a time (Windows and NTFS are quite slow applying ACLs) than correctness perspective (some files are locked, with explorer complaining, ecc).

If you want to proceed anyway, you have two possible ways to mitigate the risk:

1. introduce ACLs to remove `Everyone` access operating at the *share* level, rather than at the file level. In other words, you left the file's ACLs intact, but you change the share ACLs to remove the unwanted access. This is a nearly instantaneous operation which can be very easily reverted
2. operate at the file level but changing only *some directory* at a time. For example, if having 20 top level directories, you can change the ACLs on the first one only, see if all works properly, than proceed with the second, ecc.

Comment: Thank you very much @shodanshok, actually I already done what you suggested by gradually change the permission when some directory had problem when someone delete or moved the directory. It really mad not only the directory share permission went insane but also last person in charge in IT make user scheme that share user per department not creating per user and assign  a group. I guess I will stick with you suggestion and gradually change it. Thank you very much for your though.